# datagridviews in visual studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

everyone ... for tragic reasons I had to downgrade from visual studio 2012 to visual studio 2010 ... the problem is that, it's acting weird!

I've a tabbed window with datagridview binded to datasets with oracle DB , I'm setting some columns visibility to false and enabled editing in gridview in each tab

on building the app, the visibility of the columns changes from itself ("i was showing only 2 columns then on runtime it showed me everything") , no editing in one of the gridviews ("though it's already enabled in the designer form")

my colleagues advised me to close the designer form before building, and restart the visual studio or PC if necessarily when this happens...

it really works sometimes, but is there any other solution ?!!!

Answer (score 0):

Using DataGridViews inside TabPages is a bit buggy. Try setting the TabPage containing the DataGridView as the selected tab before changing your DataGridView properties.

e.g. `TabControl1.SelectTab(1)` to select the second tab.

Comment: Thank you, that reduced it but still gridviews are acting crazy...
the read only and visibility properties also the column reordering change from itself !

i've to close designer and all opened tabs and restart visual studio/pc to open it properly.

Comment: Check that `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = False`